# Add scope with optional parameters to routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I don't want to create admin scaffolds for any new resources. But I do want my models to be controlled by `Admin::VariousResourcesController`. I would like to pass a `:class` parameter to that controller so to instantiate that class and do all resourceful actions on it.

The current URL looks like:

```
admin/various_resources?class=User&role=Admin
```

But, I want the URL to look like this:

```
admin/various_resources/users/?role=Admin
```

How can I customize the structure of resourceful routes? What should I change in `routes.rb`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do this -

```
scope '/:class' do
  resources :various_resources, path: ''
end
```

Comment: How would this help? This only affect named route helpers. Sorry if my question is unclear.

Comment: That is really close but you have to put something inside `scope` block to define some routes inside.